# How should I set up my git remote repo to deploy websites?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-push

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to deploy my sites using git, I set up a bare repo on my server so I can push my local repos to it and it works fine but I have a few questions:

Let's say my repo is inside my `public_html` folder in my server, if I create it using `git init --bare` I'd just be able to push my local `.git` folder so I won't have access to my working directory files, and if I create a regular repo with `git init` I get a warning everytime I try to push saying that I shouldn't be pushing to non-bare repos. So what should I do? Github for example does store my working files but I don't get the weird warning message.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two choices really:

1) Have the actual website pull from your bare repo on a regular basis (eg, via cron)

2) Have the actual website pull form your master repo (assuming it's accessible via a pull and the changes end up in master (or similar) and you don't ever commit things to master that aren't ready to go)

3) Use a hook in the bare repo to execute a `git pull` in the real location after the push is completed.  If you go this route, be sure to unset the GIT_DIR environment variable that will end up being set in the hook's environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up using your first suggestion with a few modifications, I set up a repositories folder with just bare repos on my server and on the `public_html` folder I'd just manually pull the master branch of any of them to make them accesible,